# How to make sure the user enter a positive number

Tags: c

I did this, but sadly it is not working, and crashing when input is char/string, etc.

How do I fix it?

```
while((scanf("%d",&numOfDef) != 1 ) && (numOfDef>0 ))
{
  printf("not a pos num try again");
}
```

Comment: numOfDef>0 is exactly the opposite of what you need, try with numOfDef<1

Answer (score 0):

Actually, two changes need to be made: `while((scanf("%d",&numOfDef) >= 0 ) && !( numOfDef>0 ))`

Firstly, compare return value of `scanf` with 0, secondly the condition should be either `!( numOfDef>0 )` or `( numOfDef<=0 )`

Return value of `scanf`(Source: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-10/)
:

> In C, printf() returns the number of characters successfully written on the output and scanf() returns number of items successfully read.

Ideone link for code: http://ideone.com/TjtuDy

Comment: If scanf fails it returns a 0, in which case the loop ends, and numOfDef doesn't get set. The variable remains uninitialized. This is not the desired behavior.

Comment: when I the thing you suggested ,its not crashing but also skip the while, even tho not inputing a positve intger

Comment: You are close, but scanf will can actually return a negative value if it fails. So you only have to fix that.

Comment: @RazBenNetanel: Can you provide the ideone link with inputs where it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
numOfDef = 0;
while((scanf("%d",&numOfDef) != 1 ) || (numOfDef<=0 ))
{
  printf("not a pos num try again\n");
  int ch;
  while((ch=getchar())!= '\n' && ch != EOF);
  if(ch == EOF){
      numOfDef = 0;
      break;
  }
}
if(numOfDef == 0)
    puts("Processing was discontinued.");
...
```

Comment: It can not be said to be an error. because due to what the desire OP.

Comment: You may be rewritten their own answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is often easier to handle input as a character string, even when taking numerical input from the user, and then convert the string to a number:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char buf[32] = {0};
    int num = -1;

    while (num < 0) {
        printf (" Enter a positive number: ");
        if (scanf (" %[^\n]%*c", buf) == 1) {
            if (*buf < '0' || *buf > '9') continue;
            sscanf (buf, " %d", &num);
        }
    }

    printf ("\n You entered : %d\n\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/positive_entry
 Enter a positive number: --1--1 1--1
 Enter a positive number: #%@#&%$ u08$
 Enter a positive number:  wise guys^2
 Enter a positive number: -127
 Enter a positive number: -3
 Enter a positive number: a
 Enter a positive number: 2

 You entered : 2
```

Comment: if scanf fails( returns a non 1 value ), the loop ends, and you print a value that is not positive.

Comment: You can protect against corner cases by adjusting the test. This is an example.

Comment: Sure, I was just mentioning that since it wasn't made clear by OP what the exact requirement are.

Comment: Ok, go beat up on the new one and let me know if you break it `:p`

Comment: Yes it works if you separate by newline: https://ideone.com/6YGCh8 But you don't check if scanf succeeded.

Comment: What happens if someone enters more than 31 characters in one line ;)